# Attempting to create a histogram of given values in a dictionary using numpy, not all values are showing up

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matplotlib, histogram

I am currently attempting to create a histogram that charts the values from a dictionary I created. I have searched for similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22python%22%20%22histogram%22%20%22dictionary%22) on here but I am still confused on this block. Apologies if this is a repeat question.

The dictionary olf_kmer_hits currently look like this: 
{AAAAAAAAAAAA: -1.333}. I am interested in plotting each value for this dictionary. However, I am not seeing all my values: [histogram output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE2Dt.png). I should have values from -2.5 to 2. One part of the code where I'm not sure is

- I have 85K values I am trying to plot. Could it be a size issue? I am using Jupyter notebook.

The code is below.

```
for score in olf_kmer_hits.values():
    k_m = np.histogram(score)
plt.hist(k_m)
plt.title('Histogram of {} 12aa K-mers'.format(len(olf_kmer_hits)))
plt.ylabel('Number of K-mers')
plt.xlabel('HOPS average score')
plt.axis([-1, 1, 0, 9.5])
plt.show() #there should be 85,984
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it is important in python.

Comment: Right now, you are overwriting `k_m` each time through your loop.  So you only save the last value in the loop. Although with your indentation I can't tell if that is what you want or not.

Comment: Just changed the indentation. This is how it was supposed to look.

Comment: So with this you are overwriting your histogram every time through your loop.  Your plot only shows the last histogram in the loop.  You probably want to do `np.histogram([score for score in olf_kmer_hits.values()])` or something.

Comment: Could I append "score" to a list and plot that instead?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what you want to do.

Comment: _removed_ my comment

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed my code and this is giving me the correct [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc4uw.png).
Thank you @chrisz for the help.

```
score =[k_score for k_score in olf_kmer_hits.values()]
#np.histogram(score) #edit:1 np.histogram isn't being used
value, bins, patches = plt.hist(score)
plt.title('Histogram of {} 12aa K-mers'.format(len(olf_kmer_hits)))
plt.ylabel('Number of K-mers')
plt.xlabel('HOPS average score')
plt.axis([-4.5, 2.5, 0, 47000])
plt.show() #there should be 85,984
```

Comment: why are you calling `np.histogram`? The result is not used afterwards

Comment: Oh, I was under the assumption that calling that function would automatically calculate the bins for me. Yes, commenting out that line works the same. Thank you @xg.plt.py.